# Can't manage to place custom Markers on Google Map

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I managed to get a script working for my Map needs but I can't manage to customize the markers.

Here what I have

HTML:

```
<div id="map_wrapper">
    <div id="map_canvas" class="mapping"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#map_wrapper {
    height: 400px;
}

#map_canvas {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

JS:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  // Asynchronously Load the map API 
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=initialize";
  document.body.appendChild(script);
});

function initialize() {
  var map;
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  var mapOptions = {
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
  };

  // Display a map on the page
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
  map.setTilt(45);

  // Multiple Markers
  var markers = [
    ['London Eye, London', 51.503454, -0.119562],
    ['Palace of Westminster, London', 51.499633, -0.124755]
  ];

  // Info Window Content
  var infoWindowContent = [
    ['<div class="info_content">' +
      '<h3>London Eye</h3>' +
      '<p>The London Eye is a giant Ferris wheel situated on the banks of the River Thames. The entire structure is 135 metres (443 ft) tall and the wheel has a diameter of 120 metres (394 ft).</p>' + '</div>'
    ],
    ['<div class="info_content">' +
      '<h3>Palace of Westminster</h3>' +
      '<p>The Palace of Westminster is the meeting place of the House of Commons and the House of Lords, the two houses of the Parliament of the United Kingdom. Commonly known as the Houses of Parliament after its tenants.</p>' +
      '</div>'
    ]
  ];

  // Display multiple markers on a map
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(),
    marker, i;

  // Loop through our array of markers & place each one on the map  
  for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
    bounds.extend(position);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: position,
      map: map,
      title: markers[i][0]
    });

    // Allow each marker to have an info window    
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
      return function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent[i][0]);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      }
    })(marker, i));

    // Automatically center the map fitting all markers on the screen
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  }

  // Override our map zoom level once our fitBounds function runs (Make sure it only runs once)
  var boundsListener = google.maps.event.addListener((map), 'bounds_changed', function(event) {
    this.setZoom(14);
    google.maps.event.removeListener(boundsListener);
  });

}
```

So everything works well but I need to customize the marker images. Someone can help me with this?

Comment: if I don´t miss something your are not even trying to change the icon.

Comment: related question: [Change point location of multiple custom marker icons Google Map API V3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18091343/change-point-location-of-multiple-custom-marker-icons-google-map-api-v3)

Comment: duplicate of [Adding multiple custom markers to a google map using an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33241379/adding-multiple-custom-markers-to-a-google-map-using-an-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you generate the marker you can set an icon. I don´t see where you are trying this, but you can do it this way:

Define the icon:

```
var icon = {
                url: "/myIcon.png", // url
                scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(30, 30), // scaled size
                origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0), // origin
                anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0) // anchor
            };
```

Then while you create the marker do:

```
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: {lat: lat, lng: lng},
        icon: icon,
        map: map
    });
```

You should read the documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference

Please let me know, if it´s what you expected.